# Multiple file in one Stream, custom stream

Tags: c#, .net, stream

According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40103387/best-way-to-return-large-file-as-split-zip-files-stream-or-byte-array-wcf) I want to write multiple files stream to one stream as following:

4 byte reserved for length number of each stream
each stream content write after it's length number(after 4 byte)
at the end stream will be something like this

**Stream = `File1 len + File1 stream content + File2 len + File2 stream content + ....`**

Example code:

```
result = new ExportResult_C()
            {
                PackedStudy = packed.ToArray() ,
                Stream = new MemoryStream()
            };
            string[] zipFiles = Directory.GetFiles(zipRoot);
            foreach (string fileN in zipFiles)
            {
                MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileN));
                MemoryStream len = new MemoryStream(4);
                //initiate outFile len to 4 byte push it to main stream
                //Then push outFile stream to main stream
                //Continue and do this for another file 
            } 
            //For test Save stream to file(s)
```

is it good idea? really don't know how that comments can be lines of code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing wrong with packing data into a single stream.  If the steam contains multiple types you may also want to add a one byte message type after/before byte count.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, no all the file have one type (zip), but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] testMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
            MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(outFile);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
            {
                writer.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(testMessage.Length), 0, 4);
                writer.Write(testMessage, 0, testMessage.Length);
            }
            writer.Flush();

            outFile.Position = 0;
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(outFile, Encoding.UTF8);
            while (outFile.Position < outFile.Length)
            {
                int size = reader.ReadInt32();
                byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes(size);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing different, that was just the variable name, so the `outFile` will be the stream of all files?

Comment: How it should be read in consumer side, should I use `BinaryReader`?

Comment: Thanks, but nothing happened, I have passed `outFile` as stream.

Comment: Check Position and Length of stream to make sure there is data.  Also help to flush writer to make sure all data is pushed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126955/discussion-between-aria-and-jdweng).

Comment: The position has to be set to zero to zero before reading.  I updated the code.

Comment: Your code runs without prob like a charm, but there is a little problem as: 1- I have passed `result.Stream` instead of `outFile` to `BinaryWriter` 2- I read and save each `data` to file after 3-but when get stream from service in client that stream position is not 0 and I think there is no stream in returned `result.Stream` do you know why that happened?

Comment: Either you didn't push the last byte of data with a flush, or you have to wait until all the data has arrived.   Not sure if result.stream is from http, tcp, or Network Stream.  Http you have to wait for a done status (200).  TCP you can get packets with zero bytes.  With TCP it is best to add an additional count at the beginning(either total number of bytes or total number of packed messages).

Comment: Using TCP tfro communication between consumer and service, I am returning `result` but in consumer side the `CanSeek`,`CanTimeOut` and `CanWrite` are false and the `Length`  got exception.

Comment: TCP splits messages into ~1500 byte datagrams, So you have to combine datagrams into total message.  There is no stream unless you are using Network Stream.  TCP can have zero byte messages which are keepalive (datagram with no data).  So you have to wait until you have enough bytes to read.  You can read faster than the data is arriving which will give errors.

Comment: Before this everything was working good and I was returning stream in any protocol I have tested it for many time before this , but from what I have changed the code as your solution stream will not returned like before, anyway thanks for your attention and help.

Comment: I knew this was going to happen.  I didn't test for an under-flow condition where position + size > length.

Comment: Can you take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423822/fill-stream-by-binarywriter-and-get-it-from-client-not-works-wcf).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better solution I posted as answer to my question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423822/multiple-stream-in-one-stream-will-not-passed-to-client-properly)
multiple file byte will be serialized to one stream and in client side it will be deserialized to a class of byte array.

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423822/multiple-stream-in-one-stream-will-not-passed-to-client-properly), it may be useful.

But I have accepted the [@jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng) solution and I appreciate his attention and help.