# Multiple stream in one stream will not passed to client properly

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, stream, wcf-binding

In WCF service I fill Stream according to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317625/multiple-file-in-one-stream-custom-stream) like :

```
   result.Stream = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(result.Stream);
            foreach (string fileN in zipFiles)
            {
                byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileN);
                writer.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(fileBytes.Length), 0, 4);
                writer.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            }
            writer.Flush();
            return result;
```

before this I was returning stream by this and everything works in service and client side:

```
 result.Stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileN));
```

Stream be `MessageBodyMember`
but nut now changed it to save all file in one stream.

and Test method in client side:

```
 ExportClient export = new ExportClient("exportEndPoint");
        ExportResult_C result = export.Export(source);
        result.Stream.Position = 0;
        //result.Stream.SaveToFile("d:\\kkk.log");
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(result.Stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        string pathToSave = string.Empty;
        while (result.Stream.Position < result.Stream.Length)
        {
            int size = reader.ReadInt32();
            byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes(size);
            pathToSave = "D:\\test\\" + new Random().Next(0, 2564586).ToString() + ".zip";
            File.WriteAllBytes(pathToSave, data);
        }
```

the endpoint address:

```
 <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:2082/Exchange/Export.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="largeSizeStreamTcp"
    contract="xxx" name="exportEndPoint"/>
```

and binding configuration:

```
 <netTcpBinding>
    <binding openTimeout="00:00:03" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferSize="2000000000" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="2000000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000000" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="largeSizeStreamTcp"  transferMode="Streamed" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" openTimeout="00:00:01" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" maxBufferSize="2000000000" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="2000000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000000" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
```

I believe endpoint and binding is correct as I was able to return one file stream and save it back but now there is no prob in service side but when it will get from client side, Stream got lost it's content,length,position.

this is really drive me up the wall!!!

does anyone know why this is occurred(in client side) ?

Comment: I think the binding is bad or the service associated with binding.  Make sure the service is getting the stream.  Is the client sending or receiving the data?  It looks like the code posting is receiving stream.  Is the server sending the stream?  I don't see any port numbers so the port may be blocked.  Use port number > 10,000 so it doesn't conflict with other application and doesn't get blocked.  Ports under 1024 can get blocked.

Comment: No, as I said I was returning file steam like `new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileN))` however now can return stream by before code again it is returned to client side and save it back(many time tested), the port number and endpoint address is properly configed.

Comment: If the TCP is configured properly, then you can send data without the bindings?  Is the issue only with the bindings?  Can you ping LocalHost in a cmd.exe?  Not all computers have LocalHost configured.  On the same PC, the client and server cannot use localhost at the same time.  The server usually uses IP.Any.

Comment: Sir, If something went wrong with my service it should not be able to pass stream to client by `result.Stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path))` and in client side(`retrieved stream is nice`) it can be saved, but when I want to pass multiple files as stream by your suggested code it doesn't works in client side (`retrieved stream is null`) so I think the problem is something else.

Comment: The test case was using one memory stream so it was necessary to set the position to zero. In the actual code your transmit stream and receive stream are physically different streams so you don't need to set the position to zero.  The TCP data will be received in blocks of ~1500 bytes.  You also are not writing all data to one file.  You are writing each block into a seperate file with a random filename.

Comment: So, what should I do to correct this in action?, there are several samples by googling but all of them are returning `byte[]` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wooow, Finally I get success to implement our scenario properly, going to put the answer here maybe someone wants to use the solution to returns multiple files in one stream.

there are several sample to return multiple files but all of them are returning byte array, I prefer to return stream because of many reason, the important thing is streams will perform better for large files since not all of it needs to be read into memory at one time and backward compatibility for my case.

So at the **first step** I have created a serializable `DataContract` to hold the name of file and it's content byte.

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class ExportSourceFiles_C
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;
    [DataMember]
    public byte[] Content;
}
```

at the **second step** a list of `ExportSourceFile_C` will be created like:

```
List<ExportSourceFiles_C> sourceFiles = new List<ExportSourceFiles_C>();
string[] zipFiles = Directory.GetFiles(zipRoot);
foreach (string path in zipFiles)
  {
     byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
     sourceFiles.Add(new ExportSourceFiles_C()
     {
         Name = Path.GetFileName(path),
         Content = fileBytes
     });
  }
```

at the **third step** the mentioned list should be serialized to `result.Stream` like:

```
  result.Stream = new MemoryStream();
  BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
  formatter.Serialize(result.Stream, sourceFiles);
  result.Stream.Position = 0;
  return result;
```

in client side this is enough deserialize the stream to list of `ExportSourceFiles_C` so the last step in client side should be something like this:

```
 ExportClient export = new ExportClient("exportEndPoint");
 ExportResult_C result = export.Export(source);
 BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
 List<ExportSourceFiles_C> deserialisedFiles = (List<ExportSourceFiles_C>)formatter.Deserialize(result.Stream);
 foreach (ExportSourceFiles_C file in deserialisedFiles)
      File.WriteAllBytes("d:\\" + file.Name, file.Content);
```

everything works like a charm without any problem.

enjoy.